# Errors occured when using RDLC to generate pdf files in multi-threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, pdf, rdlc

I met an issue when I used RDLC to generate pdf files in WF service with multi-thread:

I have a WF service running in high concurrency, within one of its activity I need to make some pdf files with RDLC, the ReportViewer dlls and RDLC file are of 10.0. For getting higher performance we use multi-threads, the code to generate pdf files is like below:

```
public class ReplicaMaker
{
    public void MakeReplica(object emailInfo)
    {
       EmailInfo email = emailInfo as EmailInfo;

   using (LocalReport rpt = new LocalReport())
   {
       rpt.ReportPath = "c:\ReplicaTempalte.rdlc";
       rpt.EnableExternalImages = true;

       List<ReportParameter> rptParams = new List<ReportParameter>();

       {
          ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("From", email.From);
          rptParams.Add(param);
       }

       ...

       {
          var rptFilePath = new Uri(tempChartFileName);
          ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("ChartFilePath", rptFilePath.AbsoluteUri);
          rptParams.Add(param);

          report.SetParameters(rptParams);
       }

       while (!report.IsReadyForRendering)
       {//Wait until the report is ready to render
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }

       bytes = report.Render("pdf");
       fileSize = bytes.LongLength;

       //Save pdf file
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
       {
           fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           fs.Flush(true);
           fs.Close();
           fs.Dispose();
       }
   }
}
```

}

Each thread will create an independent instance of ReplicaMaker.

The issue is after the WF services ran about 30 minutes, there will be many exceptions occur, like

1. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Error creating window handle.
2. Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'C:/1.rdlc' is invalid.
3. System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Even worst, the WSWP.exe for this WF service will crash and be re-created by IIS.

It seems that some resources were not released on time.
Could somebody tell me what's wrong with it?